# Instagram app's native browser for Android not copying to clipboard from code

Tags: javascript, android, instagram, clipboard, inappbrowser

My first question here after more than a year of daily use. :)

Never needed to ask something that wasn't already answered. But thist time I tried some research here and everywhere, but didn't find a solution. I see some old questions about this browser, and people trying to find workarounds, some of them just asking users to open page from Chrome (menu option).

Most of sells from my client are made inside Instagram, and I just faced 3 issues this week:

1. That browser doesn't seem to respect cache headers, and is not updating the page even after 24 hours.
2. Redirect client from button click didn't work too: window.location.replace, window.location, location.href and all those other options to take user to another place simply do nothing.
3. But the main issue I didn't find a solution yet is the clipboard. The feature is copy a discount code to clipboard when button/link clicked or when code is loaded/shown. But none of clipboard methods I tried work.

Obs: Instagram for iPhone doesn't have any issue with in-app browser. Everything working as expected.

My nightmare is even worse because more than 80% of my client's users access the page from Instagram and Android.

Is there any documentation for this browser? It doesn't seem to even be listed on the MDN compatibility chart, unless it uses some other browser's engine.

1. For cache not updating issue, we had to change url to people who already accessed old version be able to access new one. :/
2. For redirect not working from click event, we had to use anchor  and dinamically change href property to make that button is working. Although this would likely break the Clipboard API as it is not a click event and requires a permission request. But at least it redirects the client to the destination while I don't find better solutions for copying and redirecting by clicking.
3. For the main issue, clipboard, I tried these methods:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

`Using the Clipboard API` or `Using execCommand()`

The text is from a variable, but for execCommand I used the method of using textarea element.
All of them worked very well with other browsers, but simply none of them with Instagram Android browser.

Clipboard seems to be inaccessible. :/